# Find and return key/object number based on search in js

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, xml, search

I have a large xml file that I need to edit based on a search of the file. I am only editing a single character. The data is layed out like this. I can successfully change the very first result as it is item "0". I need to search all fields named "event name" for a keyword and change the "active" value to a 1 or 0. My current JavaScript code will follow below.

I am using Node.js for this.

The data file structure

```
`<events>
  <event name="FIND THIS VALUE">
    <nominal>1</nominal>
    <min>1</min>
    <max>1</max>
    <lifetime>1800</lifetime>
    <restock>0</restock>
    <saferadius>0</saferadius>
    <distanceradius>0</distanceradius>
    <cleanupradius>0</cleanupradius>
    <flags deletable="1" init_random="0" remove_damaged="1"/>
    <position>fixed</position>
    <limit>child</limit>
    <active>CHANGE THIS VALUE</active>
    <children>
      <child lootmax="20" lootmin="20" max="1" min="1" type="ChristmasTree_Green"/>
    </children>
  </event>
</events>`
```

This code changes my XML to a JSON, edits it and saves it back as an XML. I need a search function incorporated.

```
    var fs = require("fs"),
    parseString = require("xml2js").parseString,
    xml2js = require("xml2js");

    fs.readFile("MY-FILE.xml", "utf-8", function(err, data) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
  

    parseString(data, function(err, result) {
    if (err) console.log(err);

    var json = result;




    //HERE IS THE PROBLEM....This does change the very first Event's Active to 0  
    json.events.event[0].active = "0";
    


    var builder = new xml2js.Builder();
    var xml = builder.buildObject(json);

    fs.writeFile("MY-FILE.xml", xml, function(err, data) {
      if (err) console.log(err);

      console.log("successfully written our update xml to file");
    });
  });
});
```

Here is a raw snipit of the data.xml

```
{
  "events": {
    "event": [
      {
        "$": {
          "name": "FIND THIS VALUE"
        },
        "nominal": [
          "1"
        ],
        "min": [
          "1"
        ],
        "max": [
          "1"
        ],
        "lifetime": [
          "1800"
        ],
        "restock": [
          "0"
        ],
        "saferadius": [
          "0"
        ],
        "distanceradius": [
          "0"
        ],
        "cleanupradius": [
          "0"
        ],
        "flags": [
          {
            "$": {
              "deletable": "1",
              "init_random": "0",
              "remove_damaged": "1"
            }
          }
        ],
        "position": [
          "fixed"
        ],
        "limit": [
          "child"
        ],
        "active": [
          "CHANGE THIS VALUE"
        ],
        "children": [
          {
            "child": [
              {
                "$": {
                  "lootmax": "20",
                  "lootmin": "20",
                  "max": "1",
                  "min": "1",
                  "type": "ChristmasTree_Green"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },


Thank you very much for any assistance.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Have you tried replacing the single write with a loop that writes to all entries?

You have the following line that writes to entry #0 only:

```
    json.events.event[0].active = "0";
```

Have you tried this:

```
    json.events.event.forEach(event => {
        if (event["$"]?.name === "FIND THIS VALUE"){
            event.active = "0";
        }
    })
```

The `forEach` causes the statements in the loop to be repeated for each event.

Comment: I haven't tried that but I will. Thank you so much. My apologies but im away from my pc to give it a go.

Comment: I finally got home and tried it out. Its returning the following error.

TypeError: json.events.forEach is not a function

Comment: Sorry I didn't realise you have an extra piece of structure, inside `events`, called `event`, that is not itself an event, but an _array_ of events. I have updated the code - try it and let me know! 8-)

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thank you so much. JS is hard lol. I am trying to learn tho.